# Single Signin With AAD and B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

We're trying to implement a single sign in using both AAD and B2C. The web app needs to allow internal and external people to login in. I'm able to implement each method individually, but is it possible to determine the login method based upon email addr. If they're an external person, I would authenticate with B2C. If internal, AAD.

Any suggestions or is this even possible,

Answer (score 0):

For OIDC, "[domain_hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect#domain-hint)" would work.

"The domain hint can be used to skip directly to the sign-in page of the specified identity provider, instead of having the user make a selection among the list of available identity providers".

**Update**

The usual way to do this would be to authenticate with B2C and then add a login button to AAD i.e. [federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I don't think it helps me unless I don't understand. I need to use both AAD and B2C for authentication. AAD would be used for internal people. B2C for external.

Comment: Use this answer in combination with this sample https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-page